# How to override the GroupInterface by creating extension attributes in magento 2

Tags: backend, customer-group, save, extension-attributes, interface

I wish to override Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface to add my custom fields.

Custom fields are 
1.custom_terms
2.handling_fee

I have created the below file in etc/extension_attribues.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_terms" type="string"/>
        <attribute code="handling_fee" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>

</config>
```

I have created two additional  columns to save my extension attribute values in a customer_group table
[image]

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace PPC\CustomerGroup\Controller\Adminhtml\Group;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;

class Save extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Group\Save
{
    protected $groupExtensionInterfaceFactory;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
                                GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
                                GroupInterfaceFactory $groupDataFactory,
                                \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
                                \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
                                \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
                                \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupExtensionInterfaceFactory $groupExtensionInterfaceFactory)
    {
        $this->groupExtensionInterfaceFactory = $groupExtensionInterfaceFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry, $groupRepository, $groupDataFactory, $resultForwardFactory, $resultPageFactory, $dataObjectProcessor);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $taxClass = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('tax_class');
        $customTerm = $this->getRequest()->getParam('custom_terms');
        $handlingFee = $this->getRequest()->getParam('handling_fee');

        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface $customerGroup */
        $customerGroup = null;
        if ($taxClass) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            try {
                $customerGroupCode = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('code');
                if ($id !== null) {
                    $customerGroup = $this->groupRepository->getById((int)$id);
                    $customerGroupCode = $customerGroupCode ?: $customerGroup->getCode();
                } else {
                    $customerGroup = $this->groupDataFactory->create();
                }
                $extensionAttributes = $customerGroup->getExtensionAttributes();
                $customerExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->groupExtensionInterfaceFactory->create();
                $customerExtension->setCustomTerms($customTerm);
                $customerExtension->setHandlingFee($handlingFee);
                $customerGroup->setCode(!empty($customerGroupCode) ? $customerGroupCode : null);
                $customerGroup->setTaxClassId($taxClass);
                $customerGroup->setExtensionAttributes($customerExtension);

                $this->groupRepository->save($customerGroup);

                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the customer group.'));
                $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/group');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                if ($customerGroup != null) {
                    $this->storeCustomerGroupDataToSession(
                        $this->dataObjectProcessor->buildOutputDataArray(
                            $customerGroup,
                            \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface::class
                        )
                    );
                }
                $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/group/edit', ['id' => $id]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect;
        } else {
            return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('new');
        }
    }
}
```

So my problems are below

1. How do I check whether the extension attributes are created or not?
2. The values are not saved in the customer_group table. 
   Can anyone guide me if I missed anything?

Comment: Did you try to save custom values using plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have created two fields like custom_terms and handling_fee.

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\SavePlugin.php

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;

class SavePlugin {

  protected $_filterBuilder;
  protected $_groupFactory;
  protected $_groupRepository;
  protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;

  public function __construct(FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder, GroupFactory $groupFactory)
  {
    $this->_filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->_groupRepository = $groupRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->_groupFactory = $groupFactory;
  }       

  public function afterexecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Group\Save $save, $result)
  {   
    $customTerms = $save->getRequest()->getParam('custom_terms');
    $handlingFee = $save->getRequest()->getParam('handling_fee');  
    $code = $save->getRequest()->getParam('code'); 
    if(empty($code))
      $code = 'NOT LOGGED IN';
    $_filter = [ $this->_filterBuilder->setField('customer_group_code')->setConditionType('eq')->setValue($code)->create() ];
    $customerGroups = $this->_groupRepository->getList($this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($_filter)->create())->getItems();
    $customerGroup = array_shift($customerGroups);
    if($customerGroup){
     $group = $this->_groupFactory->create();
     $group->load($customerGroup->getId());
     $group->setCode($customerGroup->getCode());
     $group->setData('custom_terms',$customTerms);
     $group->setData('handling_fee',$handlingFee);
     $group->save();
    }
    return $result;
  }       
}
```

Please try above code to save data.

Comment: Hi, I have already saved the fields. But It failed to show or prefilled with the saved values while doing edit